# How would you translate "mind you" in German

Tags: translation

How would you translate the expression "[mind you](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mind+you)" in German, a phrase introducing something that should be taken into consideration. For example: "He's very well dressed, but mind you, he's got plenty of money to buy clothes".

Comment: [Leo translates it as "wohlgemerkt](http://dict.leo.org/ende?search=mind+you) (too lazy for a propper answer ;-))

Comment: here is Pons' translation:

http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=mind+you&l=deen&in=&lf=de

that was REALLY hard to find,mind you

Comment: In contrary to Emanuel ;p It was very easy to find, this comment took more time: [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/mind+you.html)

Comment: [First page, first and forth results on Google](http://www.google.co.il/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&site=&source=hp&q=mind+you+german&oq=mind+you+german&aq=f&aqi=g-bK4&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0i8i30l4.4909.6618.0.6797.15.14.0.1.1.1.162.1672.7j7.14.0...0.0.074WWQTdGpE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=64e5b9892c909ff8&biw=1680&bih=900) are very interesting and good and correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this example I would probably just use "allerdings", or say ".., aber er hat ja auch genug Geld..."

Comment: Too bad I can't give this more than +1 ... Excellent translation!

Comment: In this specific example, "er kann sich's (ja) auch leisten" is possible, too.

Comment: Ein Hoch auf Modelpartikel!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think these are the best solutions. "Wohlgemerkt" or "noch dazu..." are much closer to the meaning of "mind you". Don't forget it is an imperative explicitly drawing the listeners or readers attention to a certain aspect. You have to mirror this in German which you can't do sufficiently with "allerdings" (restricting the initial statement) or "ja auch".

Answer (score 12):

A somewhat literal but not too uncommon German expression would be *"bedenke"*, the imperative of *"[bedenken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bedenken)"*:

> Er ist gut angezogen, aber **bedenke**, er verfügt auch über genügend Geld, sich Kleidung zu kaufen.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about this one: seems to me, the imperative of "bedenken" is rather stilted in most contexts. A more common construction would be "..., man muss/sollte aber bedenken, dass er auch über genügend Geld verfügt, sich Kleidung zu kaufen." It still sounds rather official to me, as opposed to the casual feel of "mind you".

Comment: The "casual" solution in German would be to just leave the intermission out of the sentence altogether: "Er ist gut angezogen, aber er hat auch genügend Geld, sich Kleidung zu kaufen".

Comment: Ich würde "denk dran" statt "bedenke" verwenden, insbesondere umgangssprachlich.

Comment: "Bedenke" doesn't fit at all. Try translating back.

Answer (score 8):

The *intent* of a more literal translation like "**bedenke**" (du sollst denken) would be like *raising your hand to point something out*.

Therefore, the following translations should fit:

- ...**bedenke**, er hat viel Geld um Kleidung zu kaufen.
- ...**da** er ja viel Geld hat um Kleidung zu kaufen.
- ...**freilich** hat er viel Geld um Kleidung zu kaufen.
- ...**zugegeben**, er hat viel Geld um Kleidung zu kaufen.
- ...**wohlgemerkt**, er hat viel Geld um Kleidung zu kaufen.

Comment: +1 für *freilich*.

Answer (score 5):

> "He's very well dressed, but mind you, he's got plenty of money to buy clothes".

'wobei' ist, zumindest in mündlicher Rede, recht üblich:

> Er ist sehr gut gekleidet, wobei er es sich auch leicht leisten kann.

Answer (score 2):

In German you can simply use `aber` or `schließlich`, but it sounds weird. Usually I wouldn't translate it at all.

> "He's very well dressed, but mind you, he's got plenty of money to buy clothes".
>
> Er ist immer sehr gut angezogen, er kann es sich auch leisten.
>
> Er ist immer sehr gut angezogen, aber er kann sich das auch leisten.
>
> Er ist immer sehr gut angezogen, schließlich kann er es sich leisten.

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use is "Gib Acht," or pay attention. That is a fairly literal translation of "mind you."

Another, English term would be "remember." As in, "He is well dressed, but remember that he has a lot of money. The German verbs would be "merken," or 
bedenken, in the imperative, "merk," or "bedenk."

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. "Mind you" as an idiomatic phrase in English has very little to do with "pay attention", has it? You'd be right, when it's a construction like, "Mind you don't step into that" - but that's a different construction with an elided "that", I think.

Comment: I agree with Tom, In my mind "mind you" is a short for "please take this into your mind for a minute".

Answer (score 0):

In my mind "mind you" is short for "would you please bear in mind that...".

German word "beachten" (swedish "beakta") means to bear something in mind or take something into consideration. Please bear this in mind. The polite version would be

> beachten Sie, dass er genug Geld dafür hat.